# Python find which order element is in in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a program which asks the user for a sentence, gets each word, and stores it in a list called words.

```
text = raw_input("")
    words = map(lambda x:x.lower(), re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  text).split())
```

Like this.

Now, I want to see which word has the word "name". I have written:

```
for listelement in words:
        if listelement == "name":
            name = listelement[This is what I want to find]
```

How should I find it?
Speed is not really a concern, though the faster it is, the better.

**EDIT**: I'm trying to get the user's name by putting the sentence "My name is * ", separating it by words, detecting where the word "name" is in the list, add 2 to the position of "name" and saving it as the variable uname.

Comment: Do you mean `i = words.index("name")` ?

Comment: If the sentence is always `My name is *` then `name = sentence[len("My name is "):]` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can do this really easy with

```
words = 'the horse and the rider'.split(' ')
look_for = 'the'
indices = [i for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == look_for]
print(indices)
```

This would print `[0, 3]`

**Edit:**

<s>This solutions works for multiple occurences.</s>

After the OP has rephrased his question, I would suggest something like

```
text = "My name is Alice and his name is Bob"
words = text.split(' ')
indices = [i+2 for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == 'name']
names = [words[i] for i in indices if i < len(words)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `index` method. It will return the first occurrance of an item in a sequence:

```
In [1]: string = 'this is a test'

In [2]: words = string.split(' ')

In [3]: words.index('is')
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: words.index('test')
Out[4]: 3

In [5]: words.index('foo')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7345c027ead9> in <module>()
----> 1 words.index('foo')

ValueError: 'foo' is not in list
```

Comment: Wouldn't work properly if there are multiple occurrences of "name" in the input list. So if the input string is `the horse and the rider` it wouldn't work because "the" occurs twice.

Comment: Because there is no repetition(probably), and this worked, I am choosing this as the solution.

Comment: @YuBinLee It might work here, but you better not use it if you're testing many different input files. This is a working solution, but not an extensible, adaptable solution. So it is not good code.

Comment: @PythonGuy Changed the solution to something more adaptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position using `list.index(value)`

```
try:
   pos = listelement.index("name")
except:
   print("name not in the list")
```

Comment: I twitched a little at `except:`.

Answer (score 0):

To find the index of the first occurrence of `'name'` consider this generator,

```
next(i for i,w in enumerate(words) if w == 'name')
```

In most cases this proves faster than iterating over an entire list comprehension.